# Pass variable into Step Function start_execution() input parameter

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-step-functions

I am using `boto3` with `Python 3.6` to start a Step Function execution. The Step Function is designed to share my base AMI across all my accounts. I have 4 variables I need to pass to the `input` parameter to kick off the execution. These are the AMI ID, the account list of accounts I own, the source account, and the KMS key. The AMI ID and the account list are constructed in my code and are the variables that need to get passed dynamically. According to the documentation, `input` is a `string that contains the JSON input data for the execution` and gives the following example: `"input": "{\"ami_id\" : \"ami_id\"}"`. My question is how do I pass the variables in question to this parameter as the value? My code is below with the traceback:

`CODE:`

```
import boto3
import json

#   Get an STS token to assume roles into AWS accounts
def get_sts_token(**kwargs):
    role_arn = kwargs['RoleArn']
    region_name = kwargs['RegionName']
    sts = boto3.client(
        'sts',
    region_name=region_name,
    )
    token = sts.assume_role(
        RoleArn=role_arn,
        RoleSessionName='GetInstances',
        DurationSeconds=900,
    )
    return token["Credentials"]

def get_accounts():
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/list-accounts-role"
    region_name = "us-east-1"

    token = get_sts_token(RoleArn=role_arn, RegionName=region_name)

    access_key = token['AccessKeyId']
    secret_key = token['SecretAccessKey']       
    session_token = token['SessionToken']

    client = boto3.client('organizations', 
    aws_access_key_id=access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
    aws_session_token=session_token)

    moreAccounts=True
    nexttoken=''
    global accountList
    accountList =[]

    while moreAccounts:
        if (len(nexttoken)>0):
            accounts=client.list_accounts(NextToken=nexttoken)
        else:
            accounts=client.list_accounts()
        if 'NextToken' in accounts:
            nexttoken=accounts['NextToken']
        else:
            moreAccounts=False
        for account in accounts['Accounts']:
            if account['Status'] != 'SUSPENDED' and account['Status'] != 'CLOSED' :
                account_id = account['Id']
                accountList.append(account_id)


    print(accountList)

def trigger_sfn():
    ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/execute-sfn"
    region_name = "us-east-1"

    ami_id = ssm.get_parameter(Name='/BaseAMI/newest')['Parameter']['Value']
    print(ami_id)

    token = get_sts_token(RoleArn=role_arn, RegionName=region_name)
    print(token)

    access_key = token['AccessKeyId']
    secret_key = token['SecretAccessKey']       
    session_token = token['SessionToken']

    sfn = boto3.client('stepfunctions', 
    aws_access_key_id=access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
    aws_session_token=session_token)

    response = sfn.start_execution(
    stateMachineArn='arn:aws:states:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:stateMachine:ami-share',
    input="{\"ami_id\": ami_id, \"source_account_id\": \"112233445566\", \"accountList\": accountList, \"kms_key_arn\": \"alias/aws/ebs\"}"
)

    print(response)
```

`TRACE:`

```
An error occurred (InvalidExecutionInput) when calling the 
StartExecution operation: Invalid State Machine Execution Input: 
'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 
'ami_id': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
at [Source: (String)"{"ami_id": ami_id, "source_account_id": 
"112233445566", "accountList": accountList, "kms_key_arn": 
"alias/aws/ebs"}"; line: 1, column: 18]': InvalidExecutionInput
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 6, in lambda_handler
trigger_sfn()
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 96, in trigger_sfn
input="{\"ami_id\": ami_id, \"source_account_id\": \"112233445566\", 
\"accountList\": accountList, \"kms_key_arn\": \"alias/aws/ebs\"}"
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 612, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidExecutionInput: An error occurred 
(InvalidExecutionInput) when calling the StartExecution operation: 
Invalid State Machine Execution Input: 
'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 
'ami_id': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
at [Source: (String)"{"ami_id": ami_id, "source_account_id": 
"112233445566", "accountList": accountList, "kms_key_arn": 
"alias/aws/ebs"}"; line: 1, column: 18]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the value of the variable to the string like this:

```
input="{\"ami_id\": \"" + ami_id + "\", \"source_account_id\": \"112233445566\", \"accountList\": accountList, \"kms_key_arn\": \"alias/aws/ebs\"}"
```

Your code currently sends the literal string "ami_id", instead of the variable value of ami_id

Comment: This worked after testing. Is there any documentation you have on json variables?

Comment: [This might help you](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), it shows how you can turn the JSON into a string using .dump function. The approach you have right now is writing the JSON in string format from the start, which is why it works when we add the ami_id string to the rest of the string. If you want to make it neater, you could form the JSON using json.dumps

Comment: OK, so the output is now failing again because there are no quotes around the `ami_id` value. Is there a way I can pass the variable and add quotes around it, too?

Comment: Yupe, I edited my answer, as it should technically be with quotes

Comment: How does one access this input parameter from inside the step function?

Comment: man, how can I debug what's wrong? I provided a VTL script and how can I debug that?